# Assigning value in 2D array not working - swapping indices

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, console, 2d

Basically I have a 2D array of which looks like this:

```
0 x x -1
x 0 x x
x x 0 x
-1 x x 0
```

If using two for loops (nested) with indices 'i' and 'j' and if they equal each other, e.g. i and j = 2, then the value placed in array[i, j] will be '0'. If 'i' = array.Length - 1 and 'j' = 0 (or vice versa) then value in array[i, j] will be -1.

What I'm trying to do is place random numbers between 1 and 20 in the places denoted by 'x'. I know how to do this, but, I want the numbers in the 'x' on the other side of the '0's to be equal. For example,

value @ i = 2, j = 3 is equal to value @ i = 3, j = 2.

Now I've already done this in a previous program by doing:

```
array[j, i] = array[i, j]
```

But for some reason in this new program this no longer works, at all.

What's wrong?

Here's the actual code:

```
size = r.Next(4, 8);
        V = new int[size, size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            s = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    V[i, j] = 0;
                }
                else if ((i == size - 1 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == size - 1))
                {
                    V[i, j] = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    V[i, j] = r.Next(1, 20);
                }
                V[j, i] = V[i, j];

                s += "|" + V[i, j] + "|";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with the algorithm is that its re-overwriting (overwriting twice) the lower half of the matrix.
try this loop instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    s = "|";
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            V[i, j] = 0;
        }
        else if (i == size - 1 && j == 0 || i == 0 && j == size - 1)
        {
            V[i, j] = -1;
        }
        else if (i < j)
        {
            V[i, j] = r.Next(1, 20);
            V[j, i] = V[i, j];
        }
        s += $"{V[i, j],2}|";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```